# Is there a Silverstripe has_many field more basic than HasManyComplexTableField?

Tags: silverstripe

I'm modelling a very basic association between courses (`CoursePage`) and instances of that course (`CourseInstance` extending from `DataObject`):

```
class CoursePage extends Page {
    public static $has_many = array('Instances' => 'CourseInstance');
}

class CourseInstance extends DataObject {
    public static $has_one = array('Course' => 'CoursePage');
}
```

What I want in the CMS is a simple way to add course instances to the course page. The `HasManyComplexDataField` is working but means that all course pages have the same (long!) list of instances shared across all courses. What I want is a way to add / remove / edit just instances relating to that course, without any details of instances from any other `CoursePage`.

Is there a more simple field more suited to my needs? Alternatively, is there any way I can limit the complex field to only show related instances but also allow me to add new ones?

Comment: Is setting the sourceFilter to `'CourseID = ' . $this->ID` sufficient? It seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `sourceFilter` parameter of the `HasManyComplexDataField` to the following works:

```
'CourseID = ' . $this-ID
```